# How to properly drop capabilities?

Tags: c++, linux

In a C++ program I need the capabilities:

dac_override
setuid
setgid
chroot

I don't need any others, and I'd like to drop them immediately in the program, and then drop the others later on.

What is the proper method for doing this?

edit for clarity:

So, I have root, which is really just a bunch of capabilities. My program does not need almost any of these caps, so I want to drop all but the four I mentioned. I believe the way to do this is with somethingl ike:

```
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_DROP,CAP_SYS_CHROOT, 0, 0, 0);
```

but when I do

```
if(prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ,CAP_SYS_CHROOT, 0, 0, 0) == 1)
    err(0, "CAP_SYS_CHROOT drop fail");
```

I get an err. And I can still chroot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out. The best method here is to use libcap-ng.

The following code works for me.

```
capng_clear(CAPNG_SELECT_BOTH);
capng_updatev(CAPNG_ADD, (capng_type_t)(CAPNG_EFFECTIVE | CAPNG_PERMITTED), CAP_SETUID, CAP_SETGID, -1);
capng_apply(CAPNG_SELECT_BOTH);
```